# listen to that song? or listen that song?

Tags: grammar

Do we say listen to that song (if I want to ask someone to listen to the song I forwarded?)

Also do we refer to song as "music" listen to that music? or song is correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Listen to the song": "To listen" is an intransitive verb, so requires a preposition when it takes an object (most often probably "to", "for", and "with").